# Android native crash: Could not write wake signal to fd

Tags: android

A native crash happened in my Android application. This happens when I am running monkey test. From the error message and crash stack, it seems like a system problem. But I don't know about this error. My question is what does this crash mean? How can I solve it?

```
// CRASH: com.my.app (pid 4552)
// Short Msg: Native crash
// Long Msg: Native crash: Aborted
// Build Label: Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys
// Build Changelist: 11.5.250_200614
// Build Time: 1592147934000
// *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
// Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/heart/heart:10/QKQ1.191014.001/11.5.250_200614:userdebug/test-keys'
// Revision: '0'
// ABI: 'arm'
// Timestamp: 2020-10-16 14:19:20+0800
// pid: 4552, tid: 5214, name: plumber-android  >>> com.my.app <<<
// uid: 10292
// signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
// Abort message: 'Could not write wake signal to fd 99 (returned -1): Bad file descriptor'
//     r0  00000000  r1  0000145e  r2  00000006  r3  c5d66e18
//     r4  c5d66e2c  r5  c5d66e10  r6  000011c8  r7  0000016b
//     r8  c5d66e28  r9  c5d66e18  r10 c5d66e48  r11 c5d66e38
//     ip  0000145e  sp  c5d66de8  lr  f1f0f4cb  pc  f1f0f4de
// 
// backtrace:
//       #00 pc 000604de  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: b8ea1bc56f976308b1ee7e2335b3127e)
//       #01 pc 00005a95  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+176) (BuildId: 87a4fc52c4da52007b41b9baaa778d64)
//       #02 pc 0001066f  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::wake()+110) (BuildId: 303a9d221465f0db9b5d760e0a0c6abe)
//       #03 pc 00289b47  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+102) (BuildId: 39c685939f0d8867d4162c7a38d63ad3600807fd)
//       #04 pc 0204f797  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage+470)
//       #04 pc 0204f797  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage+470)
//       #05 pc 02034cad  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage+108)
//       #06 pc 02053cb5  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime+244)
//       #07 pc 0205d139  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed+120)
//       #08 pc 020a22cd  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.post+76)
...
```